# Toggle between Like and Unlike Asynchronously in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am implementing my own Like/Unlike system for my website. The PHP part is already done and all working, but I'm trying to make the Like/Unlike process all asynchronous with jQuery's AJAX methods.

What I'm trying to achieve is let an user press the like button and then the like button will become yellow (like being pressed) and the URL will change to *unlike* and when clicked, the user will basically unlike the item and the button will get its original color again.

The liking part is already working, but I'm failing to toggle between these two.

This is what I've been trying:

HTML/TWIG:

```
<li><a href="{{ S_IMAGE_NAME }}?do={% if S_IMAGE_LIKED == true %}un{% endif %}like" data-image-action="likeUnlike"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" {% if S_IMAGE_LIKED == true %}style="color: #f0c36d;" title="Unlike"{% else %}title="Like"{% endif %} data-placement="right"></span></a></li>
```

jQuery:

```
$('[data-image-action="likeUnlike"]').click(function(e){

    var likeHref    = $(this).attr('href');
    var likeUnlike  = (likeHref.indexOf('unlike') != -1) ? 'unlike' : 'like';
    var unLikeUrl   = likeHref.replace(!likeUnlike, likeUnlike); // This is wrong, but how else do I do this?
    var thumbColor  = (likeUnlike == 'like') ? '#f0c36d' : '#eee';

    $(this).attr('href', unLikeUrl);
    $('.image-options .glyphicon-thumbs-up').attr('data-original-title', ucfirst(likeUnlike));
    $('.image-options .tooltip-inner').text(ucfirst(likeUnlike));
    $('.image-options .glyphicon-thumbs-up').css('color', thumbColor);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: likeHref,
        success: function(data){

            // console.log(data); return;
            var response = $.parseJSON(data);

            if ('error' in response)
            {
                display_alert(response.error, 'danger', 3000, 'top');   
                return;
            }

            $('.likeCount').text(response.likeCount);
        }
    });

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

After refreshing the page, the logic works great enough with the Twig if statements, but I want to achieve the same without having to reload the page.

So again in summary:

- User clicks *Like*
- Glyphicon turns yellow, title changes to *Unlike* and URL changes to *unlike*
- User now clicks *Unlike*
- Glyphicon turns light greyish, title changes to *Like* and URL changes to *like*

How can I achieve this? What's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> // This is wrong, but how else do I do this?
> likeHref.replace(!likeUnlike, likeUnlike);
> ```

Basically you want to replace the current state with its reverse (which is not what the boolean NOT does for us :-) ). The current is `likeUnlike`, so do

```
var unlikeLike = (likeUnlike == 'like') ? 'unlike' : 'like';
```

Now, since `replace` does take a regular expression, we can simply match both possible wordings and replace them with the new:

```
var unlikeHref = likeHref.replace(/(un)?like/g, unlikeLike);
```

Comment: Yeah, I know that negating just like that returns `false`, but I just wanted to make a point that I need the opposite. Thinking what I did a few minutes earlier, makes me chuckle. Anyway, your solution works great, thank you!

Comment: Well, visually, it's alright, however when I try to make the `url` in the AJAX call is always sending the opposite - so when hitting *like* it's calling *dislike* and vice-versa. This is my code momentarily: http://pastebin.com/fkeHDLYR

Comment: You still should ajax to the original `likeHref`, not to the new `unlikeHref`

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. Could you briefly explain this situation? I'm quite confused.

Comment: The `likeHref` is the current `href` attribute, the action that you want to happen. The `unlikeHref` is the url that you want to appear after the action, to undo it.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot happening in your code. Try to isolate the bits and pieces.

Firstly, your problem does not seem to have anything to do with the ajax request, unless that's throwing an exception for some reason. Changing the link url and the icon style when a user clicks on it should be simple though.

My suggestion on how proceed in debugging, step by step:

- Check the browser console (eg. firebug) for any js exceptions
- Ignore the ajax request and just focus on toggling the link url and icons style in the click event.
- Check the value of the href attribute and all the other variables that are being set.
- What is returning `ucfirst`, upper case first string?

Also, you will want to prevent the user clicking on the like/unlike link while the ajax request is in progress.

I hope I could help with this.